# Changing old UK light switch to modern switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have a two-gang switch with pre 1970 wiring.
One switch is one way to bathroom and other switch is a two-way switch for hallway. The first picture is old switch with bathroom switch on the left of the picture, second picture is the switch that I want to use.

Can someone tell me which wire goes where on the new switch please.

[image: Old Switch]

[image: New Switch]

Comment: Does [this description](https://www.homehow.co.uk/blog/wiring-colours) (the first link found in a search for "uk wiring colour code") answer your question?

Comment: The colours aren't truly important, it's their relative tasks. It's all a switched live circuit, with the permanent live jumpered to both sides. As no-one ever bothers putting helpful sheaths on anything, it's all context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new switch is essentially the 'other way up' visually.

So, without rotating,

- Take the red & black from the lower right & move to the upper right 1 & 2.
- Take the single black & move it to upper left 1.
- Move the pair of reds to lower left Com & the single jumper from that to lower right Com.

As you don't seem to have any earth in the old wiring, it would be safest to use a plastic back box rather than a metal one. No, it's not to current regulations, but it's 'better' than the regulations when that wiring was first installed.

Comment: your instructions are precise and very clear and easy to follow. I have completed changing the switch for the new one. Thank you. I do not have the option to change the back box to plastic, it is not easy to remove without damaging the wall. Again, thank you, this had me confused until I read your reply and instructions. @Tetsujin

Comment: Good to hear. The only trouble with a metal back box is the [remote] possibility of a live coming loose & touching the box, which would then make the two patress screws on the faceplate live. It is extremely unlikely, but that's what the earth is for, to prevent that. btw, if this helped, could you mark it with the 'tick' [check] on the left of the answer - it helps future searchers know what was useful.

Comment: Yes, I understand the risk but without an expensive whole hose rewire, I have to go with what I have. I have marked with the tick, as requested. Thank you once again